# call child method when parent method called

Tags: c#, methods, parent-child

I have a class and it has a method:

```
public class A{
    public virtual void doChanges (String message, object[] args){
    }
}
```

Some classes use 'doChange' method in 'A':

```
public class MethodClaller{
    A a = new A();
    public void caller(){
        a.doChanges ("Test",null);
    }
}
```

And **ALL** child classes should override doChanges:

```
public class B:A{
    public override void doChanges(String message, object[] args){
    }
}
```

Problem is: I want to use Class **A** and Class **MethodCaller** in several programs(like component) and in each program, method **doChange** should automatically call for all childs of **A**, whenever **doChange** called for **A**. so a code like this:

```
new MethodCaller.call();
```

should call **doChanges** in all instances of **B**.

It sounds like event handling. But I don't know how to do it. It doesn't matter if **A** and **B** are not relative as parent and child in solution. I just had feeling that this is the correct structure.

Comment: I think simplest way is to call base.doChanges() in doChanges() of derived class.

Comment: One thing that concerns me slightly. You say it doesn't matter if A and B are parent and child. Is there a reason for them to not be related? Does B need anything from A or do you simply want a function of B to fire off every time a function in A fires off?

Comment: No they are not related in any way. Just like to fire function of B  every time function of A called. and consider that I can't change codes where they call function A to call function A then call function B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using inheritance where a pattern is in order.

Instead of `B` inheriting from `A` (which is just a static dependency between the two classes) you should register the *instances* of `B` so that an *instance* of `A` can *delegate*. Look up the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to understand this sentence.

Doing this is the first conceptual step, but later on you will *probably* (nobody can say it for sure) end up with something larger, which is the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

To have the instances automatically registered in the composite, you'll use the creational [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

It will go like this:

- `A` will allow its instances to be composites;
- `B` will be a component that may be attached to `A`;
- you will fave a factory method on `B` to instantiate elements of `B` which requires an instance of `A`:

  ```
  A a; // get the instance "a" from somewhere
  B.Create(a); // will create an instance of B and attach it to a
  ```

To force this usage you'll `private`ize the constructor of `B` as the usual (see factory pattern).

The `Create()` will be something like this:

```
private B() // prevent direct instance creation
{
    // ...
}

public static void Create(A a)
{
    B b;

    b = new B();
    a.Register(b);
}
```

So you're sure **ALL `B`** are atached to an `A` (analog of your requirement *all B must extend A*).

The `Register()` in `A` will be:

```
private List<B> _bs = new List<B>();

public void Register(B b)
{
    _bs.Add(b);
}
```

The `Do()` in `A` will be:

```
public void Do(object args)
{
    // pre-procedure of A

    foreach (B b in _bs)
    {
        b.Do(args);
    }

    // post-procedure of A
}
```

Now to be sure that `B` implements the `Do()` method without using the static dependency between classes leverage the composite pattern by defining a component interface:

```
interface AComponent
{
    void Do(object args);
}
```

Derive `B` from it:

```
class B implements AComponent
{
    ...
```

And finally refer the interface (instead of `B`) from `A`:

```
private List<AComponent> _components = new List<AComponent>();

public void Register(AComponent component)
{
    _components.Add(component);
}

public void Do(object args)
{
    // pre-procedure of A

    foreach (AComponent component in _components)
    {
        component.Do(args);
    }

    // post-procedure of A
}
```

The last step is decouple `B` from `A` in the create method by using a composite interface:

```
interface AComposite
{
    void Register(AComponent component);
}
```

Derive `A` from it:

```
class A implements AComposite
{
    ...
```

Use the interface in the create method:

```
public static void Create(AComposite composite)
{
    composite.Register(new B());
}
```

Now you have `A` and `B` loosely coupled but instances of `B` must be registered on instances of `A` so that when `Do()` fires, all instances of `B` also fire their `Do()` methods.

As a benefit you can have implementations of `AComponent` that are completely different from `B` (as per inheritance) and still have them fire their `Do()` methods, to. You can even mix-up instances of different implementations of `AComponent`, just like polymorphism allows through virtual methods.

Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Thanks for your time. As I see to call B.Create I should have a pointer to instnace of A? number of instances of A is exactly "1". So a single tone method to get instance of A whould be good?

Comment: If on a conceptual level `A` as a singleton makes sense then yes, implement it as such and use as usual `GetInstance()`. If you just have one instance but on a **conceptual** level it is not a singleton then don't. Just have a normal class instantiate only one instance and use that.